# Regex join elements if directly next to each other

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have the following script which allows me to select text, and will then visually highlight it by wrapping the selected text in a `span` tag.

This normally works fine, but if there is a highlight tag separated from another highlight tag by only a space, it joins the two highlights together.

### Javascript

```
var HVleftPanelContent = $("#highlight-view .top .content");
    HVoutputUl = $("#highlight-view .contentBottom ul");

$("p").on("copy", highlight);

function highlight() {
    var text = window.getSelection().toString();
    var selection = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
    var selectedText = selection.extractContents();
    var textStr = selectedText.textContent;
    if (textStr == "\n") {
        clearSelection();
        return false;
    } else if (textStr[textStr.length - 1] == "\n") {
        textStr = textStr.slice(0, -1);
        var reg = new RegExp("\n", "g");
        textStr = textStr.replace(reg, "\n<b data='&#xa;'></b>") + "\n";
    } else if (textStr.indexOf("\n") >= 0) {
        var reg = new RegExp("\n", "g");
        textStr = textStr.replace(reg, "\n<b data='&#xa;'></b>");
    }
    var span = $("<span class='highlight'>" + textStr + "</span>");
    selection.insertNode(span[0]);
    if (selectedText.childNodes[1] != undefined) {
        $(selectedText.childNodes[1]).remove();
    }
    var txt = HVleftPanelContent.html();
    HVleftPanelContent.html(txt.replace(/<\/span>(?:\s)*<span class="highlight">/g, ''));
    HVoutputUl.html("");
    $("#highlight-view .top .content .highlight").each(function () {
        $("#highlight-view .contentBottom ul").append("<li><span>" + $(this).html() + "</span></li>");
    });
    saveIt();
    clearSelection();
}
```

### Recap

If HTML looks like this:

```
This is a short paragraph
```

And I highlight "is", the markup changes to:

```
This <span>is</span> a short paragraph
```

And then I highlight either "this" or "a", the markup erroneously changes to:

```
This <span>isa</short> paragraph
```

Instead of how it should change:

```
This <span>is</span> <span>a</span> paragraph
```

### Potential Problem

I assume the problem lays in this line:

```
HVleftPanelContent.html(txt.replace(/<\/span>(?:\s)*<span class="highlight">/g, ''));
```

Where the Regex statement is joining `<span>` tags that are next to each other, which it should so that if two `span` tags are **directly** next to each other, it becomes one `span`, but the Regex isn't limiting the joining to only when they're **directly** next to each other.

So, basically, how can I change the Regex to only join span tags if they're directly next to each other.

Comment: You are aware that when joining elements like that, you can't get the events bound to both and bind them to the new `span`, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fairly simple, replace:
`HVleftPanelContent.html(txt.replace(/<\/span>(?:\s)*<span class="highlight">/g, ''));`

With:
`HVleftPanelContent.html(txt.replace(/<\/span><span class="highlight">/g, ''));`

The problem was `(?:\s)*`, which means match any white space 0 or more times, which means that it would match even the spans that are separated with spaces.

Comment: @Charlie That's possible, but why ? You want to merge the spans and if you did that it would highlight unwanted characters.